# ElasticSearch - not setting the date type

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying the ELK stack, and so far so good :)

I have run in to strange situation regardgin the parsing the date field and sending it to ElasticSearch. I manage to parse the field, and it really gets created in the ElasticSearch, but it always end up as string.
I have tried many different combinations. Also I have tried many different things that people suggested, but still I fail.

This is my setup:

The strings that comes from Filebeat:

> [2017-04-26 09:40:33] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"securitysecured_area"} []
>
> [2017-04-26 09:50:42] request.INFO: Matched route "home_logged_in". {"route_parameters":{"controller":"AppBundle\Controller\HomeLoggedInController::showAction","locale":"de","route":"homelogged_in"},"request_uri":"https://qa.someserver.de/de/home"} []

The logstash parsing section:

```
if [@metadata][type] == "feprod" or [@metadata][type] == "feqa"{
 grok {
   match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}" }
 }
date {
#timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
match => [ "logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, my @timestamp field should be overwritten with the logdate value. But it is no happening.

In the ElasticSearch I can see the field logdate is being created and it has value of 2017-04-26 09:40:33, but its type is string.

I always create index from zero, I delete it first and let the logstash populate it.

I need either @timestamp overwritten with the actual date (not the date when it was indexed), or that logdate field is created with date type. Both is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are explicitly adding `[@metadata][type]` somewhere that you aren't showing, that is your problem.  It's not set by default, `[type]` is set by default from the 'type =>' parameter on your input.

You can validate this with a minimal complete example:

```
input {
    stdin {
        type=>'feprod'
    }
}
filter {
    if [@metadata][type] == "feprod" or [@metadata][type] == "feqa"{
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}" }
        }
        date {
            match => [ "logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }
}
```

And running it:

```
echo '[2017-04-26 09:40:33] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"securitysecured_area"} []' | bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

And getting the output:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-05-02T15:15:05.875Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxxxxx",
       "message" => "[2017-04-26 09:40:33] security.DEBUG: Stored the security     token in the session. {\"key\":\"securitysecured_area\"} []",
          "type" => "feprod",
          "tags" => []
}
```

if you use just `if [type] ==`... it will work fine.

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-04-26T14:40:33.000Z,
       "logdate" => "2017-04-26 09:40:33",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxxxxx",
       "message" => "[2017-04-26 09:40:33] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {\"key\":\"securitysecured_area\"} []",
          "type" => "feprod",
          "tags" => []
}
```

Comment: [@metadata][type] the type is being set with filebeat, so I know what index to store the logs. Thanks for explanation :)

Comment: according to this discussion: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-input-beat-not-receiving-metadata-field/40365/3 it doesn't appear that the filebeat @metadata fields come over to logstash

Comment: In Filebeat: 
- input_type: log
  paths: mylog.log 
  document_type: feprod
Emits the feprod as type, which I use in Logstash to make decision what index to store the data